# Calculating percentile buckets and appending them to an existing table in R

Tags: r, percentile

I am working with a dataset of around 8500 lines in R and have one column with data ranging from -1000 to 25. I need to calculate what percentile relative to the column the value in each row is and append this value in an adjacent cell. Basically, I need to add another column to the table with the corresponding percentile for each value. Multiple values can have the same percentile (ie: 20.1 and 20.2 will both be in the 99th percentile).

Can anyone help me figure out how to do this? I managed to make a table that tells the cutoff for each percentile but the cuttoffs do not exactly match with my data and therefore I cannot merge the tables by.x, by.y etc.

Comment: maybe?? `cut(x, quantile(x, 0:100/100), labels=1:100)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function `ecdf` can be used to compute the percentiles :

```
x = runif(8500, -1000, 25)
Fn = ecdf(x)
percentiles = Fn(x)
```